# Vote early, vote often

Tags: discussion, voting

Just to echo the message from other sites that went though beta, voting helps us define the scope of the site and figure out who the experts are. To quote the [Vote early, vote often blog post:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

> Putting voting front and center is very much intentional; it is how good content is voted to the top wrong or incorrect content is voted
>   to the bottom users who consistently provide useful content accrue
>   reputation and are granted more privileges on the site It’s only
>   through voting that a class of editors, closers, and moderators can
>   emerge to help run and govern the site. Voting is how site leadership
>   forms. That’s why the reputation leagues show a breakdown of
>   reputation spectrums.

---

Just keep in mind when voting that your votes are yours. You don't have to up or down vote something just because others have.

Happy Voting.

Comment: Dom, you might wanna think a little about "voting" tag. I don't think it'll get enough traction in the future.

Comment: @MARamezani Is it harmful in some way?

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes. It's really important for tags to actually be useful for many questions. "Voting", I can't imagine how will get more questions than this one, and a few other objections on serial downvotes (which are very rare throughout per site SE metas)

Comment: "Only a few questions tagged" is not "harmful".  On Meta we aren't going to have a problem of tag overcrowding.  `voting` is a very distinct, clear, unconfusing category for questions and thus a good tag candidate.

Comment: And the most important: conscious vote.

Answer (score 15):

I would like to add that, *during the private Beta*, it is particularly important to explain downvotes.  Several questions similar to or replicating our definition questions (mine and others) have had unexplained downvotes.  We really really need to know why!

If you disagree with the entire basis of the site, you shouldn't be here.  If your views are more nuanced, then they would be very helpful in beginning to determine the shape we want the site to take.

Do feel free to bring up generalized discussions here on Meta about topics of concern if you don't wish to identify your votes or get dragged into a comment war.  As Dom says, your votes are yours.

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder, here are some voting statistics based on the awarded badges:

- **Suffrage**
  Use 30 votes in a day: **18** awarded
- **Vox Populi**
  Use the maximum 40 votes in a day: **13** awarded
- **Civic Duty**
  Vote 300 or more times: **8** awarded
- **Electorate**
  Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions: **4** awarded

This shows that 2 years after OPs message we still have a lack of votes.